# Does surface3D work in RStudio?

Tags: r, plot, 3d, rstudio, geometry-surface

The following code taken from example(surface3d) produces nothing:

```
library(rgl)  
data(volcano)

z <- 2 * volcano        # Exaggerate the relief

x <- 10 * (1:nrow(z))   # 10 meter spacing (S to N)
y <- 10 * (1:ncol(z))   # 10 meter spacing (E to W)

zlim <- range(y)
zlen <- zlim[2] - zlim[1] + 1

colorlut <- terrain.colors(zlen) # height color lookup table

col <- colorlut[ z-zlim[1]+1 ] # assign colors to heights for each point

open3d()
surface3d(x, y, z, color=col, back="lines")
```

Comment: I do no see a library call in your code to load the package that has those functions.

Comment: Adding `require(rgl)` to the code before the open3d call allows success on both a regular Mac GUI console and in RStudio.

Comment: Works for me. A new RGL device is opened.

Comment: works for me too (RStudio 0.98.191, Ubuntu 12.04, R-devel)

Comment: added the require and library calls, nothing changed. Mac OS X 10.8.4, Rstudio 0.98.501

Comment: FWIW `library(rgl)` and `require(rgl)` are redundant; you only need one or the other.  (1) Do you get any error or warning messages you haven't told us about?  (2) Do you have X11 installed? (3) What happens if you run in base R (not via RStudio)?

Comment: Is a RGL-device opened (in a new window, not the RStudio-device)?

Comment: @Edi, no RGL-device is opened

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The rgl device has indeed been opening in the X11 window which is linked to a different "desktop". That's why I did not see anything.